# Running a Script on a Webpage from Vimperator

Tags: vimperator

The problem I would like to solve is this. I browse to a website that contains ordered blocks of text one after another. I would like to run a script on this page that goes into the webpages source, extracts these blobs of text, and then outputs each blob into a file.

How do I do something like this? Can I do it from the vimperator shell?

(I can write the text extracting and output part, in python I'm thinking. The other parts are beyond me atm)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write files from Vimperator, as described [here](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/11/writing-data-to-disk-from-vimperator.html). Also, from what you're describing you don't really need Python, you could extract the text and write it from the same JavaScript file.

You can write files like this: (from the Vimperator command line)

```
:js var f = new io.File('~/extracted.txt'); f.write('extracted text');
```

To extract the text, you could use vanilla JavaScript, or you could probably source JQuery and use it's selectors. I haven't tried this, but it sounds like it's definitely doable.